# api-blueprint how to define endpoints for collection and single object with tha similar andpoints

Tags: apiblueprint

I have and endpoint that returns a collection of contacts, and it's endpoint is: .../api/v1/contact. 
Now I have another endpoint that will return a single contact, and it's endpoint is: .../api/v1/contact?Id=

```
68 ## Contacts Endpoint [/v1/api/Contact]
69 ### Retrieve All Contacts [GET]

154 ## Contact Endpoint [v1/api/Contact?id=HashID]
155 ### Get single contact [GET]
```

Now I got the following two errors:

unexpected header block, expected a group, resource or an action definition, e.g. '# Group ', '#  []' or '#  '
Line: 154• API Blueprint

action with method 'GET' already defined for resource '/v1/api/Contact'
Line: 155• API Blueprint

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle this scenario is to simply put the query parameter `id` as optional, and document the different behaviour.

However, I would try to avoid to have the same endpoint doing multiple things (return a Contact or All the contacts), so you might want to define two endpoints:

`/v1/api/Contacts`

`/v1/api/Contact/:id` (a query parameter is fine anyway)